# How can I grant a non-root user access to a root libary?

Tags: permissions, root

I want to give a non-root user the rights to view and write a specific root directory. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We probably need some additional information to help you out. What exactly do you mean by "a specific root directory"? Are you talking about "/" or a directory owned by user "root"? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the root user libary. Not about the "/".

Comment: Does this "_root user library_" have a path?

Comment: What is this root user library that you talk about? Where is it?

Comment: "/root/" is what i mean.

Comment: That would probably be a bad idea. So explain why you'd want to do this. Also check: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming **you** have root privileges, it is possible. `root` can do anything (except on newer Macs) - even if it's not ordinarily a *good idea*.

One way to do this is to use **your** root privileges to simply add your non-root user (call him `nonroot` for this answer) to the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

Once the sudoers file is open, you can add the following:

```
nonroot          ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Save & close the sudoers file, and it is done.

Note this gives user `nonroot` the same privileges as `root`.... and `root` can do anything.

But I may have misunderstood your question... If your question was how to allow `nonroot` to access files or folders under `/root` (e.g. `/root/librarydir`), the answer is a little different. Instead of the line above, add this line instead:

```
nonroot ALL = (root) sudoedit /root/librarydir/*
```

This gives user `nonroot` the ability to make changes to files in that location.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is certainly not the best solution. You'll want to put the files you want to share into somewhere a little more public.  To let everyone see it (but only the owner writes to it):

```
# mkdir -p /path/to/share/
# mv /root/sharedfile /path/to/share/
# chmod 644 /path/to/share/sharedfile
```

If you really want to give a non-root user access to `/root` consider adding them to group `sudo` or adding them to `/etc/sudoers`.  Then they can access `/root` by doing something like:

```
$ sudo ls /root
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to make the non-sudo user the owner of that particular file.

```
chown new-owner  filename
```

Comment: The question concerns a directory (possibly even one of the top-level directories), and depending on what directory this is, giving a non-root user ownership of it could break the system or provide a security hole.